# Reference for, and/or proof of, $\prod_{n=1}^\infty(\frac{4n+1}{4n-1})^{4n}(\frac{2n^2-2n+1}{2n^2+2n+1})^n=\sqrt2\cosh(\pi/2)e^{-2G/\pi}$

Tags: reference-request, closed-form, infinite-product

**Context:**
I have derived some infinite products that I think are not well known. This is the easiest of them:

$$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{4n+1}{4n-1} \right)^{4n}\left(\frac{2n^2-2n+1}{2n^2+2n+1} \right)^n=\sqrt{2}\cosh(\pi/2)\,e^{-\frac{2G}{\pi}},\tag{1}$$
where $G$ is Catalan's constant. After some searching I can't find any reference to it.

Take a look at [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=product+%28%284n%2B1%29%2F%284n-1%29%29%5E%284n%29%28%282n%5E2-2n%2B1%29%2F%282n%5E2%2B2n%2B1%29%29%5En%2C+n%3D1+to+infty&lang=es).

**Question 1:**
Do you know any reference to this or something like that?

**Question 2:**
Could you find a solution to $(1)$?

Comment: Question 2: Could we find a solution to what?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... To be clear: When you say that you have "derived" the identity, do you mean that you have proven it yourself? If so, then you should include your proof, so that people don't waste valuable time (theirs or yours) duplicating your effort or telling things you already understand. (It's no fun to conceive, edit, format, and possibly even illustrate a comprehensive solution only to have the asker respond, "Yeah, that's the way I did it.") Keep in mind that Math.SE is generally for asking questions whose answers *you do not know*, not for posing challenges. ... Cheers!

Comment: Please stop modifying your post after it has been answered.

Answer (score 6):

My goal being to obtain the partial product and then use asymptotics
$$P_1=\prod_{n=1}^p (4n+1)^{4n}=\frac{e^{\frac{1}{24}-\frac{C}{\pi }} \,16^{p (p+1)}\, \Gamma
   \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}{\sqrt{A}\,\, \Gamma \left(p+\frac{5}{4}\right)}\,\exp\left(4 \zeta ^{(1,0)}\left(-1,p+\frac{5}{4}\right) \right)$$
$$P_2=\prod_{n=1}^p (4n-1)^{4n}=\frac{e^{\frac{1}{24}+\frac{C}{\pi }} \,16^{p (p+1)}\, \Gamma
   \left(p+\frac{3}{4}\right)}{\sqrt{A}\,\, \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}\,\exp\left(4 \zeta ^{(1,0)}\left(-1,p+\frac{3}{4}\right) \right)$$
$$\color{blue}{\frac{P_1}{P_2}=\sqrt{\pi }\, e^{-\frac{2 C}{\pi }}\frac{2^{2 p+1}}{\Gamma \left(2 p+\frac{3}{2}\right)}\,\times} $$ $$\color{blue}{\exp\left(4\left(\zeta ^{(1,0)}\left(-1,p+\frac{5}{4}\right)-\zeta
   ^{(1,0)}\left(-1,p+\frac{3}{4}\right)\right)\right)}$$
For large values of $p$
$$4\left(\zeta ^{(1,0)}\left(-1,p+\frac{5}{4}\right)-\zeta
   ^{(1,0)}\left(-1,p+\frac{3}{4}\right)\right)=$$ $$2 p \log (p)+(\log (p)+1)+\frac{3}{16 p}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^2}\right)$$
$$\color{blue}{\frac{P_1}{P_2}\sim\sqrt{\pi }\, e^{1-\frac{2 C}{\pi }}\frac{2^{2 p+1}}{\Gamma \left(2 p+\frac{3}{2}\right)}\,p^{2p+1}}$$

This was the easy part.

Now, writing
$$\frac{2 n^2-2 n+1}{2 n^2+2 n+1}=\frac {(n-a_1)(n-a_2) } {(n+a_1)(n+a_2) }$$ where
$$a_1=\frac {1-i}2 \qquad \text{and}\qquad a_2=\frac {1+i}2$$

$$Q_a=\prod_{n=1}^p (n+a)^n=e^{A_a}$$
$$A_a=a \left(\zeta
   ^{(1,0)}(0,a+1)-\zeta ^{(1,0)}(0,a+p+1)\right)+$$
$$\left(\zeta ^{(1,0)}(-1,a+p+1)-\zeta ^{(1,0)}(-1,a+1)\right)$$ and using the tedious expansion of $A_a$ for large $p$ the expansion of the second product is
$$\color{blue}{\prod_{n=1}^p \left(\frac{2 n^2-2 n+1}{2 n^2+2 n+1}\right)^n = e^{-(2 p+1)} \sqrt{2 (1+\cosh (\pi ))}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^2}\right)}$$

All the above make that, at the limit, the infinite product is
$$\color{red}{\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{4n+1}{4n-1} \right)^{4n}\left(\frac{2n^2-2n+1}{2n^2+2n+1} \right)^n=e^{-\frac{2 C}{\pi }} \sqrt{1+\cosh (\pi )}}$$ which is your formula.

In terms of asymptotics, it would be
$$\sqrt{2}\, e^{-\frac{2 C}{\pi }} \cosh \left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right) \exp\left( -\frac{3}{8 p}+\frac{18}{97 p^2}-\frac{13}{188 p^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^4}\right)\right)$$

For $p=9$, the relative error is less than $0.01$% and for $p=18$ it reduces to $0.001$% .

Comment: Amazing ! Congratulations for this brilliant night work !

Comment: Claude, I think that exists a more elementary approach. Is it $\sqrt{A}$ refer to Glaisher-Kinkelin constant?

Comment: @PabloF.Refolio. Yes for $A$. The problem of the limit is "simple". What is more tedious is the asymptotics.